# Can't post under a two words label column in sheety

Tags: python-requests, label

I'm using the `requests` module to post in Google Sheets through sheety under three different columns: **First Name**, **Last Name**, **Email**.

I provided the JSON data to upload in this way:

```py
data = {
    "user":{
      "first name": first_name, 
      "last name": last_name, 
      "email": email1, 
      }
  }
```

The column under the **Email** label in the sheet is the only one which was uploaded  correctly, while the others remain blank.

I understood that I'm not giving the proper key value for a label with a space inside, i.e. **First Name**, **Last Name**, but I don't understand how to provide the key correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Sheety documentation](https://sheety.co/docs/spreadsheet), you have to use CamelCase for two words with space:

```
data = {
    "user": {
        "firstName": first_name,
        "lastName": last_name,
        "email": email1
    }
}
```